# How to restart wifie adapter or prevent it from turning off

Tags: wifi, nvidia, amdgpu

I have a repeated problem with my wifi adapter. It tends to randomly turn off, when it does, my NetworkManager becomes empty and only full restart is able to turn it on again.
It seems that this behavior happens much more often when I'm running my laptop with my Nvidia (like every couple of hours), while when the laptop is running on its AmdGPU, the network is stable for weeks.
My network adapter is:

```
$lspci -nn -s 03:00.0
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
$sudo lshw -C network 2>&1 | grep wireless | grep drive #this returned empty 
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.6-xanmod1-1 firmware=71.058653f6.0 cc-a0-71.ucode ip=192.168.1.235 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

When everything is working ok, this is my network output:

```
 *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 1a
   serial: b0:7d:64:b1:02:6a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.6-xanmod1-1 firmware=71.058653f6.0 cc-a0-71.ucode ip=192.168.1.235 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:81 memory:fc700000-fc703fff
```

When the wifi adapter disappears, I get:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:fc700000-fc703fff
```

Attempted solutions: I've googled this a lot and I did what it was suggested.
For example, my yesterday's history on my attempts to restart the adapter:

```
lsmod|grep iwlwifi
sudo rmmod -f iwlmvm
sudo rmmod -f iwlmei
sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl restart networking
nmcli networking off
nmcli networking on
sudo modprobe iwlwifi iwlmei iwlmvm
nmcli networking on
sudo systemctl restart network
lspci -nn -s 03:00.0 #this returned the same info on the adapter
sudo lshw -C network #this returned the "Network Unclaimed"
sudo lshw -C network 2>&1 | grep wireless | grep drive #this returned empty
```

Finally, I've edited /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf to be:
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8 #enabling antenna aggregation
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 swcrypto=1
options iwlwifi power_save=0\noptions iwlmvm power_scheme=1

As you can see, I've done pretty much everything suggested, at some point I also updated the firmware but that was a lot of kernels ago, so I don't know if it's still working. I thought the problem disappeared, but at the time, my nvidia was constantly off. Recently, I started using it again and the problem appeared again. It's strange for the two problems to be connected but the moment I use 'optimus-manager --switch nvidia' to use my nvidia, the wifi disappears in about an hour or two. These are my two gpus:

```
lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne (rev c5)
```

If anyone can suggest a way to deal with the wifi adapter, I'd be very helpful. I'm currently running `Linux 5.19.6-xanmod1-1 #1 SMP Fri, 02 Sep 2022 16:18:02 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux` but the problem is the same under vanilla kernel. I actually installed xanmod because I thought it's gonna be better, but the moment I installed nvidia-dkms and switched to nvidia, my wifi again became unstable. Again, I don't know if the problems are related, I'm just providing all my experience with the issue so far. And any ideas are very welcomed!

Comment: either something has a terrible, terrible firmware bug (and that's not rare for wifi adapters, sadly), or your laptop has insufficient power supply for both devices under load. I'd bet on the firmware.

Comment: did you look into `dmesg` when that happened? Anything interesting?

Comment: does it turn off when you are using the network, or only when it it is idle. In the old days, just starting an xterm and pinging google.com would prevent network links from timing out or going to sleep..   also, does this happen when you are on battery or plugged in.  have you checked the kernel logs for events around that time?   lots of bad hardware doesn't handle power savings too well.   Lastly don't forget that the wifi adapter may just be bad and need replacement.

Comment: dmesg is not very informative (it repeats "[  757.915072] wlp3s0: Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4") .
But I have a novelty - I added to "/etc/optimus-manager/optimus-manager.conf"  the line "dynamic_power_management=fine" and I have a working connection for the past 5-6 hours, Nvidia worked while I played a game (acording to nvidia-smi), so maybe it is really something about the power supply. If the 2 gpus work the whole time simultaneously....I don't know, it's very weird. Before optimus-manager.conf was empty so I don't know how it was managing the gpus.